# C function prototype with additional brackets

Tags: c, syntax

I am novice in C. Can you tell me what does it mean?

```
void (*signal(int sig, void (*func)(int)))(int);
```

I ask about syntax, not about error handling. I understand all completely except last bracket **(int)**.

```
void (*example(int sig, void (*func)(int)));
```

This is the level on which I understand. We make prototype for function which has two parameters(integer number, pointer to function with integer parameter and nothing return) and example return void.

Thank you.

Comment: Re "*This is the level on which I understand.*", Not quote. `void (*...)` doesn't mean "returns void". In fact, `void (*...)` makes no sense at all. It's half of the return type.

Answer (score 0):

It declares a function called `signal`.

- Its first argument (`sig`) is of type `int`.
- Its second argument (`func`) is of type `void (*)(int)`.
- Its return type is `void (*)(int)`.

`void(*)(int)` indicates a function pointer.

- The function's only argument is of type `int`.
- The function's return type is `void`.

The following is equivalent:

```c
typedef void (*SignalHandler)(int);

SignalHandler signal(int sig, SignalHandler func);
```

Answer (score 0):

That is to say, `signal` is a function that returns a `pointer` to another function. This second function takes a `single` int argument and `returns void`. The second argument to `signal` is similarly a `pointer` to a function returning void which takes an int argument.